# How to create new data frame based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

Need your suggestion, I have below table generated dynamically based on monthly data:

[image]

I need to compare each row across columns and create a new data frame based on priority set as **`Fish > dog > horse > cat`** such that the sample output looks like,

[image]

```r
df <- data.frame(Col_1 = c('cat', 'dog', 'cat'),
                 Col_2 = c('dog', 'horse', 'fish'),
                 Col_3 = c('horse', 'cat', NA),
                 Col_4 = c('fish', 'horse', NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with base R with `match` and `max.col`:

```
prior_vec <- c('cat', 'horse', 'dog', 'fish')

s <- sapply(df, match, table = prior_vec, nomatch = 0)

df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(s))]
```

which gives:

```
# [1] "fish" "dog"  "fish"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom order for character strings by `ordered(...)` or `factor(..., ordered = TRUE)`. In this way you could use `>`, `<`, `(p)max/min` to compare their priorities.

```r
do.call(pmax,
  c(lapply(df, ordered, levels = c('cat', 'horse', 'dog', 'fish')), na.rm = TRUE)
)

# [1] fish dog  fish
# Levels: cat < horse < dog < fish
```

###### Data

```r
df <- data.frame(Col_1 = c('cat', 'dog', 'cat'),
                 Col_2 = c('dog', 'horse', 'fish'),
                 Col_3 = c('horse', 'cat', NA),
                 Col_4 = c('fish', 'horse', NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing my solution to the ring

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    priority = intersect(c('fish', 'dog', 'horse', 'cat'), c(X1, X2, X3, X4))[1]
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   X1    X2    X3    X4    priority
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 cat   dog   horse fish  fish    
#> 2 dog   horse cat   horse dog     
#> 3 fish  fish  <NA>  <NA>  fish
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Convert the desired rows to vectors, and then take the first item from the intersect of the priority vector.
If you only want the new column change `mutate` to `transmute` (or add `,.keep = 'none'` to the mutate)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your data into a long dataset with row numbers. Then you can arrange it as per your preference after grouping based on the row numbers. Then you can use `slice` to get the desired data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~col1, ~col2, ~col3, ~col4,
        "cat", "dog", "horse", "fish",
        "dog", "horse", "cat", "horse",
        "cat", "fish", NA, NA) -> df


df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  arrange(match(value, c("fish", "dog", "horse", "cat")), .by_group = T) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(value)

# A tibble: 3 × 1
  value
  <chr>
1 fish 
2 dog  
3 fish
```

Comment: Don't quote NA when creating the data. `NA` and `"NA"` have different meanings in R. The former is a missing values and the latter is a literal character string.